# Unable to locate package python-openssl

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyenv, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to install Pyenv, and I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. but whenever I run this command

```
sudo apt install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \ libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev \ libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl \ git
```

I get this error

```
Unable to locate package python-openssl
```

I've tried searching for solutions online, but I think they have encountered it on older versions of Ubuntu and not on the latest version.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Make sure your list of packages is updated (`sudo apt update`). Python openssl bindings are available in 22.04 in `python3-openssl` ([link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/python3-openssl)), so you can install it by running

```
sudo apt install python3-openssl
```

Answer (score 7):

you must be using python3 so change python-openssl to python3-openssl in command

Comment: Yep that was it. 
notice the command "python-openssl" it should be "python3-openssl"

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt install openssl libssl-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already executed that command but still have the same error.

Comment: @Jaygee Remove `python-openssl` and replace the with his answer. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, changing from python to python3, as suggested here, worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34437237)